# Shopware : Extension-error after Shopware updating

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have updated the last version of Shopware 6.14.19.0 ( PHP 8.1.4). The problem is that the list of Plugins is not showing in the extension. I get this error :

```
"Compile Error: Declaration of Symfony\Component\Intl\Data\Bundle\Reader\BufferedBundleReader::read(string $path, string $locale) must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Intl\Data\Bundle\Reader\BundleReaderInterface::read(string $path, string $locale): mixed"
```

[image: ExtensionError]

Could you help me please ?

Comment: PHP 8.0 and 8.1 should not make a difference here. In SW 6.4.18.1 the interface method `BundleReaderInterface->read` is compatible with the implementation in `BufferedBundleReader`: `public function read(string $path, string $locale)`. But I don't have SW 6.4.19.0 here, so I would recommend to compare both files in `vendor/symfony/intl/Data/Bundle/Reader/`

Answer (score 0):

did you run something like `composer update` in the past?
i had the same problem with shopware 8.4.20.1 and just re-ran composer update. that fixed it for me.